# How to sum up Loss amount per each claim ignoring date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have table with `Loss` amount per each transaction date.

How can I create column `ClaimLoss` that would  sum up Loss amount per each claim?

```
declare @TempTable1 table (ID int, ClaimNumber varchar(100), date date, Loss money)

insert into @TempTable1 
values (1, 'Claim1','2017-01-01', 100),
       (2, 'Claim1','2017-03-06',150),
       (3, 'Claim1','2017-05-01', 50),
       (4, 'Claim2','2018-01-01', 150),
       (5, 'Claim2','2018-08-15', 250),
       (6, 'Claim2','2018-05-03', 350),
       (7, 'Claim3','2018-09-01', 330),
       (8, 'Claim4','2019-01-01', 140),
       (9, 'Claim4','2019-01-13', 225),
       (10, 'Claim5','2019-02-01', 145)

select  ID, 
        ClaimNumber, 
        Date,   
        Loss
from @TempTable1
```

[image]

I need something like this:

[image]

Is it possible to do in the same `select` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a place to use `row_number()` and `case`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by ClaimNumber order by date) = 1
             then sum(loss) over (partition by ClaimNumber) 
             else 0
        end) as claimloss
from @TempTable1 t;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `window` function:

```
select  ID, ClaimNumber, Date, Loss,
        (case when min(id) over (partition by ClaimNumber) = id 
              then sum(loss) over (partition by ClaimNumber) 
              else 0
         end) as claimloss
from @TempTable1;
```